# Auto-Fill excel columns with formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to create a To do list that I can easily manage in excel.

In column C, I would like to press 'd' - and the cell automatically inputs done, and changes the background to green.

The letter 'o' should auto complete ongoing, changing the background to purple...

... and so on, how would I go about approaching this?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a macro and assign it to a keyboard shortcut. First you will need to enable the optional "Developer" tab in the ribbon by going to File > Options > Customize Ribbons and check the "Developer" checkbox.

Then in Excel you should see the newly-enabled Developer tab. On that tab there is a section called "Code" and a button that says "Record Macro". Press it and enter a name and assign a shortcut key to your macro. Format a cell with a green background, then click the "Stop Recording" macro. Click Alt+F11 to open the VBA editor and you can see the code for your macro. Use the logic that you recorded and include new logic for changing the ActiveCell.Value to "done", etc.

Alternatively, use this code and assign a keyboard shortcut to it in the Developer tab:

```
Sub All_Done()

    With ActiveCell
        .Value = "done"
        .Style = "Good"
    End With

End Sub
```